# Converting these Matlab functions to Python cv2?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I've been asked to convert some older Matlab code (which we no longer have a license) to Python using the opencv (cv2) library. This all has to do with SURF operations generating points and descriptors in order to eventually mosaic two images together using gdal.

The two functions are:

```
points = points.selectStrongest(50000);
T = estimateGeometricTransform(points1, points2, 'affine','MaxDistance',0.5);
```

These: [selectStrongest()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/surfpoints.selectstrongest.html) & [estimateGeometricTransform()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html)

Other parts I have already figured out are dealing with reading images with imread(), setting up the SURF object, and gathering points and descriptors using detectAndCompute(), but I'm guessing that I need to first select the "strongest" points before computing descriptors.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to clear this up. Essentially, I just don't know the python equivalent to those two functions. Perhaps it's a series of python/cv2 functions that would be necessary to recreate these?

Comment: DO you need to do it EXACTLY in the way matlab does or will you be happy with the same result? I am asking this because there are plenty of examples of SURF in opencv, you should just stick to opencv examples, youll get the same result but without needing to imitate matlab code

Comment: Sure. I am having luck finding other ways of doing SURF/ORB detection for most of the steps. But I'm just not sure how to do this sort of GeometricTransform in this case.

Comment: Well the function  findHomography() (in C++ is called like that, i think the same in python) will give you the homography between the two images if you give it the matched points. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Possibly, I'll check into it. Thanks!